# What is the syntax for Nokogiri's #css and #xpath functions?

Tags: ruby, xpath, web-scraping, css-selectors, nokogiri

I'm new to web scraping and parsing and have been attempting to use Ruby and Nokogiri to parse a web page. I would like to determine the value of a particular field in an HTML table on a webpage. The HTML looks like

```
<table class="mainTable">
  <tr>The data I care about.</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
  ...
</table>
```

I've looked at examples of other people parsing HTML in similar situations, and they use the `Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment#css` or `#xpath` methods. I can emulate their results but do not understand what the syntax for these two functions is supposed to be, which I will need to know in order to create my own programs.

I'm reading the documentation at http://nokogiri.org as well as at http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/index, but neither seems to have the answer to such a basic question.

I must be missing something obvious!

Comment: "I must be missing something obvious!" – Yes: the syntax for the `css` method is CSS and the syntax for the `xpath` method is XPath.

Comment: "but neither seems to have the answer to such a basic question" Perhaps it's so basic that Nokogiri just assumes the user (e.g. you) already knows what they are and doesn't need to explain how to use them, since it's extremely unlikely anyone working with HTML in any capacity today doesn't already at least know what CSS is. This applies to many web scraping libraries.

Answer (score 0):

#css takes a CSS selector as input and #xpath takes an xpath expression, tutorials for creating which can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) respectively.

Documentation and specification for both input types:

https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/